# Symfony prevent user from re-registering with same email/username

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create login/register on Symfony (as use Symfony as a backend so I didn't use twig) but I don't want users can create multiple account with same email or username so I want to check if email or username exist before adding them to the database. During me research I heard about UniqueEntity and I do this :
(obviously I left only username and email for this example)

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email", "username"}, message="It looks like your already have an account!")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;
}
```

and when I post my request on my controller which basically look like this :

```
        $User = new User();

        $User->setEmail($jsonRequest["email"]);
        $User->setUsername($jsonRequest["username"]);
        $User->setFirstName($jsonRequest["firstName"]);
        $User->setLastName($jsonRequest["lastName"]);
        $User->setRoles((array)"ROLE_USER");

        $pass = $passwordHasher->hashPassword($User, $jsonRequest["password"]);

        $User->setPassword($pass);

        // tell Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
        $entityManager->persist($User);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)

        $entityManager->flush();
```

I got an SQL error **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry** so I wonder what's wrong and how can I achieve what I want if it's not the good way

Answer (score 1):

You're not validating the entity, that's why you're not seeing the error.
You need something like this:

```
// ...
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

// ...
public function user(ValidatorInterface $validator, ...)
{
    $User = new User();

    $User->setEmail($jsonRequest["email"]);
    $User->setUsername($jsonRequest["username"]);
    $User->setFirstName($jsonRequest["firstName"]);
    $User->setLastName($jsonRequest["lastName"]);
    $User->setRoles((array)"ROLE_USER");

    $pass = $passwordHasher->hashPassword($User, $jsonRequest["password"]);

    $User->setPassword($pass);

    $errors = $validator->validate($User);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        /*
         * Uses a __toString method on the $errors variable which is a
         * ConstraintViolationList object. This gives us a nice string
         * for debugging.
         */
        $errorsString = (string) $errors;

        return new Response($errorsString);
    }

    // tell Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
    $entityManager->persist($User);

    // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)

    $entityManager->flush();

    return new Response('The User is valid! Yes!');
}
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Also, your current UniqueEntity annotation checks whether the combination of the given username AND email address is already taken. If you want to check whether the individual username OR email address is already taken, you need two UniqueEntity annotations, like this:

```
/**
 * // ...
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username"},
 *     message="This username already exists!"
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="This email already exists!"
 * )
 */
class User
```

Comment: Is there a way to customize the error message to personalized JSON ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by personalized JSON. You can return JSON by using `return $this->json($errors, 400);` or by returning a `JsonReponse` object.